# How to show data grid view Empty from db table record?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Here is the code for displaying db table record in data grid view

```
  try
            {
                Query = "Select  Code,Description,Rate,Bottles from Items ";
                dba = new SQLiteDataAdapter(Query, GlobalVars.conn);
                testDs = new DataSet();
                dba.Fill(testDs, "Items");
                dtgitems.DataSource = testDs.Tables[0];
                dtgitems.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

What it want is when form initially Loads data grid view shouold shows empty row for insertion of new records . How i can accomplish this?Thanks

Comment: try with [DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx) property

Comment: Damith kindly tell me how to use AllowUserToAddRows Property?

Comment: The AllowUserToAddRows property can be found in the Properties window in the Design view when the DataGridView control is selected.  Alternatively, you can use DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = True in the code to enable it.

Once enabled, the DataGridView should have a row visible at all times where the user can insert information for a new entry in the table.  Once the new entry is submitted (EditMode is ended) the DataGridView will fire its adapter's InsertCommand to insert the new data into the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

```
dba.Fill(testDs, "Items");
dtgitems.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
dtgitems.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
dtgitems.DataSource = testDs.Tables[0];
```

Comment: this code is not fulfilling the mentioned requirements .It is not displaying empty data grid view .

Answer (score 0):

i use this code when i want my gridview become empty hope it helps

```
            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            dtable.Columns.Add("Delete");
            dtable.Columns.Add("FileName");
            dtable.Columns.Add("FileVersion");
            dtable.Columns.Add("FileSize");
            dtable.Columns.Add("InstallFolder");
            dtable.Columns.Add("fnameorig");
            dset.Tables.Add(dtable);
            bsource.DataSource = dset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            Gridview1.DataSource = bsource;
```